# dbus service activating method call lost

Tags: python, dbus

I use dbus by it's python bindings `dbus`. I issue calls via `dbus.call_async` to send them out fast. Some of the calls target dbus services, which may be running or will be activated upon call.

However, if a dbus service needs to be still activated, this triggers the activation, but fails to execute the call. It seems the method can't be resolved until the service is up, but there is no queue to keep the call pending until then.
dbus specs say that service activations should be totally transparent to bus users, but for python, it seems, they are not.

Of course I can backup on this, and send the call again, but this leads to abitrary repitions.

So is there any mechanism I've missed, to issue a call that is executed at the first moment it is possible, if activation is still in progress?

Comment: The [D-Bus specification guarantees that the initial message sent to a service which is then activated is queued and delivered](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-starting-services). This is known to work in D-Bus. Have you looked at a log from `dbus-monitor` of the D-Bus traffic when reproducing your problem?

Comment: My guess now is that python dbus is trying to resolve the method name by introspection first, which doesn't work while the service is not running of course. So it actually does no real call at all.

Comment: You’d still see traffic in `dbus-monitor` if Python was introspecting for the method to call. Get some `dbus-monitor` logs.

Comment: The python interface works by creating proxies for the remote objects on dbus. As there is no external metadata, application has to be activated before it can be introspected and `dbus` becomes aware of the interface. This breaks for activatable services not already running, as the proxy object may be unpopulated at the time the program is trying to call a method from it. 

So using raw messages would be the way to go I guess, this way my code provides the knowledge of methods existence and siganture and I can issue the right call message that dbus will eventually deliver after activation.